# Error calling sequence

Tags: c#

When I run it, first, it shows the average and then replace the `<userid>` with userid while it must be exactly opposite. I mean: fetch the userid from table and replace the `<userid>(url)` with `userid(table)`, then search content for find the trackid and if trackid find, `counter++`.

```
adapter.Fill(dt);
        int userid =0;
        int trackid=0;
        int counter=0;
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string url = "http://aeweewd/<userid>?groups=<userid>";
            var test = url.Replace("<userid>", Convert.ToString(row[userid]));
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(test);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
            string client = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://aeweewd/userid?groups=userid");
            if (client.ToLower() == (Convert.ToString(trackid).ToLower()))
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        int Average = counter / 2916;
        MessageBox.Show("The Average is "+counter);
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What did it do when you ran it?

Comment: I check it before. i am not sure about the second line!!

Comment: @user3233712 What about it aren't you sure about?  What do you think might be wrong with it?

Comment: cause when i run my code, it seems that it does not work

Comment: "Doesn't work" is the least helpful description ever.  What happens that shouldn't?  What doesn't happen that should?

Comment: i replaced the code with full version. when i run it, first, it shows the average and then replace the <userid> with userid while it must be exactly opposite. I mean:replace the <userid> with userid, then search content for find the trackid and if trackid find, counter++.  (PS: userid are fetched from table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any knowledge on what **xx** is, I'd say yes.

For more information check the msdn link for the DownloadString function here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Also: the strings are lowercased before being compared.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to step through the code. But download string downloads the content of the page as a string. and the if statement converts the page code to lower then compares it to xx converted to lower case.

Didnt i help you with this code yesterday?

What about this?

The using block is used to make sure that the web client is diposed. when the code inside the using block finishes.

```
using ( var webClient = new WebClient() )
        {
            string content = webClient.DownloadString(url);
            if ( content.ToLower().Contains( xx.ToLower() ) )

        }
```

Comment: Hi. it seems correct but when i run it, it seems that does not work.

Comment: @user3233712 `it seems that does not work` "It seems?", does it work or not. What did you expect? what result did it give?

Comment: "It doesn't work".it must find xx in web page. when i check the web page,the result must be true(show something as output) but it always show the same thing as before(wrong output)

Comment: so you want to see if the page contains xx? not exactly matches?

Comment: Yeap. the web content is including many numbers, I wanna check that mine is in it

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of code will **synchronously** download the contents of the `url` as a `string` (text).
In the case of a website, it's the entire HTML code.

Honestly, the code looks rather shoddy and here is what I would use instead:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
  var text = webClient.DownloadString(url);

  // Case-insensitive comparison of the downloaded data to 'something'
  if (string.Equals(text, something, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  {
     // Do something here...
  }
}
```